# call script file from Visual C++ in linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-2010, shell, wine

Please help me. I have compiled code in Windows (Visual C++) and generated .exe file in windows. I have to use this file in linux, which runs fine using wine.

My question is: I have to invoke a shell script file when this .exe is run in linux.

How do I code this in the Visual C++ program in Windows where I compile the code. I am compiling the code in Windows as there is no other option to me, it does not compile in Linux as it uses lotsa windows stuff.

I tried using System("sh my_shell_scriptfile.sh"); in the Visual C++ code, but am gettting the error, "file not found (windows path) in linux, when I run the .exe file using wine.

Please guide me

Thanks!

Comment: Try giving the absolute path to the file, and make sure you use / separators

Comment: You may have to give an absolute path to both sh and your script.

Comment: Although you would be calling that script file inside of an windows environment, which indeed should be problematic?

Comment: i tried using "./sh myfile.sh"..still does not wrk..i t says file not found

Comment: i need to run this .exe file in linux environment, and it does, but the problem is that I dont know how to make this .exe file make execute a shell script file in linux environment

Comment: @Rookie Yes, but since you are executing the binary via wine, it afaik runs in an windows environment and I'm unsure executing a script from inside that environment will work. Now I'm not an expert on Wine, but thats my qualified guess.

Comment: i tried ./ but it didnt work

Comment: can someone please guideme :(

Comment: when i give an absolute path like this "sh /home/myscript.sh" it gives an error "wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\sh.exe"
File not found"

Comment: I was able to do it! Thank you... yes absolute path are indeed accepted, but 'sh' was not getting identified in wine.. it said windows does not recognize 'sh'... so i tried "./myscript/sh" instead of "sh ./myscript.sh"